# Stop QGIS on Windows from recentering on single-click

Tags: qgis, windows

I'm using QGIS on Windows 10. In Windows, the normal UI is that when you want to bring an application forward, you can click on it. And that tends to select what you clicked on, but single-click select usually doesn't do much; double-click executes. In QGIS, most of the screen area is taken up by the map. My problem is that single-clicking on the map always causes it to recenter. I would rather turn off click-to-recenter in general, but it's especially disconcerting when I have to bring up the menu and lose my place on the map. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: I just had a hunt through the options and I don't think this is possible.  A couple of slightly clumsy workarounds - 1. keep the identify tool active instead of the pan tool (you can zoom or pan by scrolling or clicking the mouse wheel), 2. if you accidentally pan, just click the "Zoom Last" button in the toolbar without opening the menu.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will have to get used to using the Zoom Last button!

Answer (score 2):

For QGIS 3.14 and later, you can run this little script in the Python console:

```
class CanvasClickBlock(QgsMapCanvasInteractionBlocker):
    
    def blockCanvasInteraction(self, interaction):
        if interaction == QgsMapCanvasInteractionBlocker.Interaction.MapPanOnSingleClick:
            return True
            
        return False
        
        
my_click_block = CanvasClickBlock()
iface.mapCanvas().installInteractionBlocker(my_click_block)
```

Comment: Thanks! That'll be great. I just upgraded to 3.12 though... and now 3.14 just came out! Bad timing I guess. (My 3.10 install had been broken, the toolbox missing.)